# np.correlate() and signal.fftconvolve() gave different answers

Tags: python

I have 10 frames of WCDMA complex samples in SigI with the scrambling code -- Matlab Gold code (1,1) and "sc" is the variable. np.correlate() gives clean correlation spikes as expected in the code below but it is extremely slow. Try to use fftconvolve() in the same code, it detected no spikes present. fftconvolve() is fast, would like to have it work. Please tell me why it does not work?

```
mat=scipy.io.loadmat('011.mat')
SCR=mat['sc']
O1 = np.correlate(SigI,SCR,mode='valid')
# O1=signal.fftconvolve(SigI,SCR,mode='valid')
plot(abs(O1))
CC=max(abs(O1))    
print ' Max Peak = ', CC
```

Answer (score 3):

Found answer. If the conjugate of SCR is used then both np.correlation() and signal.fftconvolve() will give the same answer. But dont understand the reason though??

```
 SCR=np.conjugate(SCR[0,:])    
 O1=signal.fftconvolve(SigI,SCR[::-1],mode='valid')
```

Gave the same answer as :

```
 SCR=SCR[0,:]
 O1=np.correlate(SigI,SCR,mode='valid')
```

At least, my problem solved.

Comment: Because correlation and convolution aren't the same thing. The relation between a correlation and convolution though the conjugate of one of the inputs is a standard mathematical property. This question would probably be better addressed on the signal processing site, though.